# Hide multiple worksheets and diplay only one worksheet vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to secure my workbook, i have multiple sheets that i need to hide and leave only one sheet to be displayed that will have a command button (Picture 1) when I click on it I have a userform that pops up (Picture 2) with username and password to open specific sheets( ive set different usernames and passwords to open specific sheet) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6qgn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O16s5.png)
I wrote this code :

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim User, Pass As String

User = Me.TextBox1.Text
Pass = Me.TextBox2.Text
    If User = "Admin" And Pass = "123" Then
    MsgBox ("Bienvenu")
    Application.Visible = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Sheets("ACCEUIL").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste Personnes").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste IT").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste PE").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste EM").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste ELC").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste Habilitation").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste EPC").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste ECH").Visible = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="password"

    Unload Me
    Else



    'Pole Essais
    If User = "Admin1" And Pass = "456" Then
    MsgBox " Bienvenue"
    Application.Visible = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Sheets("Liste Personnes").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste IT").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste PE").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste EM").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste ELC").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste Habilitation").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste EPC").Visible = True
    Sheets("Liste ECH").Visible = True
    Sheets("PICHON Franck").Visible = True
    Sheets("MAGNIER Jean-Fran?ois").Visible = True
    Sheets("LAPIERRE Louis").Visible = True
    Sheets("HOSSAERT Didier").Visible = True
    Sheets("DEBEYER Nicolas").Visible = True
    Sheets("GARCIA Manuel").Visible = True
    Sheets("GIRARD Sunny").Visible = True
    Sheets("SICOT Thimot?e").Visible = True
    Sheets("BEAUVILLAIN Maxime").Visible = True
    Sheets("WATTEZ Eric").Visible = True
    Sheets("PROUVOST Thomas").Visible = True
    Sheets("PROUVOST Mathieu").Visible = True
    Sheets("GARCIA Manuel").Visible = True


    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="password"

    Unload Me
    Else
    MsgBox " Verifier le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe"
    End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
End Sub
```

`
it doesnt work as I want  the problem is when I close my workbook and reopen it I have the recent sheets That ive been working on displayed on my workbook, and I want the worksheet "ACCEUIL" to be displayed not those Ive been working on the last time I opened the workbook.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826079/hide-specific-sheets-when-closing-workbook) - it is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I tried it but its not working, I got an error on this line : Worksheets("ACCEUIL").Visible = False

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code,
maybe you can implement it to your needs.

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As Variant

'get all sheet name except "Sheet1" to array
For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
Else
ReDim Preserve arr(X)
arr(X) = sh.Name
X = X + 1
End If
Next

'hide all the sheet name in that array, so the only not hidden is Sheet1
For Each sh In arr
If Sheets(sh).Visible = True Then Sheets(sh).Visible = False
Next


'show all the sheet name in that array
For Each sh In arr
If Sheets(sh).Visible = False Then Sheets(sh).Visible = True
Next

End Sub
```

> I want the worksheet "ACCEUIL" to be displayed not those Ive been
>   working on the last time I opened the workbook.

Put your macro on the workbook module, something like this :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim arr() As Variant
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If sh.Name = "ACCEUIL" Then
    Else
    ReDim Preserve arr(X)
    arr(X) = sh.Name
    X = X + 1
    End If
Next

For Each sh In arr
If Sheets(sh).Visible = True Then Sheets(sh).Visible = False
Next

End Sub
```

You need to save the workbook before you close it.
That's if I'm not mistaken what you want.

EDIT:

> when I finish working on my database and **close the userform
>   (UF_Choix_Service)**.  I just want to know how to **hide the sheets after closing the userform**

If you want all the sheets hidden but the ACCEUIL sheet, then on the Sub where you have the line : `Unload UF_Choix_Service` try to put this line :

```
Unload UF_Choix_Service '---> this is your existing code to close the userform
For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name = "ACCEUIL" Then
else
If Sheets(sh.Name).Visible = True Then Sheets(sh.Name).Visible = False
end if
Next
end sub
```

After the code unload/close the userform, the code above say :
Loop through all the existing worksheets,
If the sheet name is "ACCEUIL", do nothing
other than ACCEUIL,
if this other sheet is visible then hide it.

Don't forget to remove the sub I ask you to put in the workbook module (BeforeClose).

Comment: look please at my answer

Comment: I got an error at this line : If Sheets(sh).Visible = True Then Sheets(sh).Visible = False, mimatch error @karma

Comment: Sorry my bad... it should be `If Sheets(sh.name).Visible = True Then Sheets(sh.name).Visible = False`

Answer (score 0):

thanks @karma it works very well, but I have something to ask, when i open my workbook i have a userform that pops up to edit/ read my database content when I finish working on my database and close the userform (UF_Choix_Service) i have all the worksheets visible again :/ but when im about to close the file I see in the background that the sheets have disappeared so your code is working good i just want to know how to hide the sheets after closing the userform.
My code to display the userfom is : (which I placed in a workbook module)

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Gestion_Comp
end sub
```

where

```
Sub_Gestion_Comp ()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Nom_Classeur = ThisWorkbook.Name
mode_edition = False
UF_Choix_Service.Show
Select Case MsgBox("Voulez vous sauvegarder le fichier ?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sauvegarde du fichier")
Case vbYes
 ThisWorkbook.Save
End Select
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uSD9.png)